# Reading XML tag value by searching with tag attribute

Tags: php, xml

For now let's say I have an XML document like this:

```
<errors>
    <viewErrors>
        <viewError code="404">Can't finde requested file</viewError>
        <viewError code="405">Method not allowed</viewError>
    </viewErrors>
</errors>
```

And I read it with this:

```
$_xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$_xml -> load("doc.xml");
$_xpath = new DOMXPath($_xml);
echo $_xpath -> evaluate( '//viewError[@code="404"]' ) -> item(0) -> textContent;
```

Which will print me "Can't find requested file" and short-term it's a goodish solution, but it's not very clean nor easy to replicate. First of all, if my XML changes to this:

```
<viewError code="404" type="test">Can't find requested file</viewError>
```

I have to modify the evaluate pattern to

```
evaluate ( '//viewError[@code="404" and @type="test"]' )
```

But with my lack of understanding in how this whole evaluation works I don't know how to read the tag content because using the item(0) -> textContent just gives "Trying to get property of non-object " error. So there are two questions:

1. Is there a cleaner way of reading XML in PHP
2. If there isn't cleaner way of doing it, how do I read the content of evaluated tag from the script above.

Comment: What's not "clean" about using XPath? You're evaluating the query, fetching the first item and read its content. You could use DOM navigation, but then you will have to loop over the errors yourself and find the matching one. I don't quite get your second question, actually you _are_ already reading the tag (actually I wouldn't call it evaluated, better say retrieved)? Your XPath expressions work for be, both the first and also the modified one.

Comment: If xpath is in fact clean solution, then second question is irrelevant. Still, using ->(0) -> textContent for two attributes doesn't seem to work; "trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: That query works for me. Can you produce an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for this problem?